# Netsuite - scheduling the same script more than once

Tags: netsuite

In NetSuite, only one instance of scheduled scripts can be in queue at a given moment.
Meaning, trying to schedule a script that is already in queue or in in progress will results in "INQUEUE" or "INPROGRESS" status and the script will be ignored.

Are there any work a rounds?
Any solutions to this issue?

I need to be able to schedule the same script multiple times.
The scheduling is done with nlapiScheduleScript, and is triggered automatically in a after submit user event.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create multiple deployments of the same queue to run them in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

NetSuite does offer clients the option to pay for more scheduled script queues. Then you would just create separate deployments for each available queue.

If that's not an option for the client, you can build a Custom record that represents your own scheduled script queue. Instead of just calling `nlapiScheduleScript`, you essentially create a custom record entry of the script to schedule with any script parameter values.

Answer (score 1):

**Same Script Receives Multiple Requests for Execution**

There may be times when you have **concurrent (simultaneous) requests** to kick off long running tasks.

In situations like this, you want to be able to schedule the next available
deployment for each request that comes in.

For **example**, if you think that at peak load you
might receive five requests in a given time frame, then you would want at least that many script deployments available to ensure that each request gets its own dedicated script deployment.
Note that if one of the deployments already happens to be in progress or in the queue, the best practice is to take the number of requests you expect over some time period (for example, over a five minute period - which is more than the average script execution time) and then multiply by two to get the number of script deployments you would need to ensure that you can handle the load. In this case you would want to create 10 deployments for the same script.

Let me know if its not clear.

```
var status=nlapiScheduleScript(scriptId,deploymentId,params)
```

So here you can use different deploymentId after checking the status to be inQueue.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Saqib's answer, you can create multiple deployments of the script then call nlapiScheduleScript and **provide a null value for the deployment ID parameter**. This will immediately execute the free and available script deployment and put it in the queue.